# How to "unignore" Visual Studio Web Site *.refresh files when you have [Bb]in/*

Tags: visual-studio, gitignore, .refresh

I'm using the standard Visual Studio .gitignore at 
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Part of that gitignore is to ignore the bin folders, but this is a problem, because I need to include bin/*.refresh files for visual studio web site projects.

When one has a (local file) web site project in: `C:\Projects\MyprojectA\MyProjectWeb` then any references to libraries are stored as "hint files" in the `C:\Projects\MyprojectA\MyprojectWeb\bin` folder as *.refresh.

So if you reference (a non framework DLL) **AjaxControlToolkit.dll**, so in the bin folder, you end up with `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` and `AjaxControlToolkit.dll.refresh`. The content of the file indicates the path of where to find that DLL.   (Let's ignore the potential pathing problems when the repo is cloned, because we're checking in the DLLs into a _lib folder that's also checked into the repo)

How does one "unignore" the *.refresh files found within Visual Studio Web Site project bin folders so that they are included with clones of the repo?

Comment: Adding a reference to .gitignore syntax, in case you (like I) did not know the meaning of ** in the answers below. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the exclamation mark.

```
**/[Bb]in/*
!**/[Bb]in/*.refresh
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using this VS feature?:

[image: VS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Once folders are excluded they can't be un-excluded.  Do it this way to include sub-folders like `roslyn`.

replace

```
[Bb]in/
```

with

```
**/[Bb]in/**/*.*
!**/[Bb]in/**/*.refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiny expansion to Alex' answer, the 'Add Ignored File' button might be hidden under the 'Git' submenu.

['Add Ignored File to Source Control' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPHeB.png)